# What should be the lucene indexing and searching strategy for providing search capabilities to end user over set of unrelated business objects?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I want to provide ability to end user to do a free form search over all business objects. The user will provide Lucene search expression. The business objects are completely unrelated and have nothing in common.

Each business object comprises of there own specific attributes. For the sake of this question, the following are the business objects:

Blog
{
    Title;
    Body;
}

User
{
    FirstName;
    LastName;
    Country;
    EmailAddress;
    Gender(M/F);
}

How could I create an index which can serve the following use-cases:

1. Free form text search in both - Blog and User. For e.g. Search those users and blog entries where the word 'India' appears. End user should not be required to specify ORing between all Lucene document fields.
2. Free form text search for only users. For e.g. Search for those users where the word 'yahoo' appears. End user should not be required to specify ORing between all Lucene document fields related to User.
3. Free form text search for only blog entries. For e.g. Search for those blog entries where either of the word 'Skeet Async' appears. End user should not be required to specify ORing between all Lucene document fields related to Blog.
4. Free form text search by attributes for blog entries. For e.g. Search those blog entries where 'asynchronous' appears in the 'Title' attribute.
5. Free form text search by attributes for users. For e.g. Search those users where 'Skeet' appears in the 'LastName' attribute.

How to define the index strategy - single index or multiple index, analyzer to use, how to provide context in the search query, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: From my own research, I've seen that Lucene does not support these type of queries (where you specify the object). To support different objects you'll have to support multiple indexes and redirect the end user based on your own parsing mechanism of what the user inputs. You'll be better off using a single index.

Comment: Also, as it stands your question is much too broad. Can you refine your question? Are you asking whether to use single index vs. multiple index? Or are you asking for a complete solution/strategy to the problem you stated?

Comment: @rae1n: Thanks for you inputs. I have tried my best to be very specific in the question. I am new to Lucene. The same solution proposed by Naresh came to my mind before I put this question on SO. I believe, that is the obvious one and there could be a better solution/strategy that respects the listed constraints. To rephrase it, I am looking for a complete and optimum solution/strategy to the use-cases that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

For the given business objects, simplest way is to have lucene documents with the following fields:

```
title, body, firstName, lastName, country, emailAddress, gender
```

You might want to have title and user-related fields as STORED.

Choice of analyzers depends on your search requirements (like do you want to support partial matches, suffix queries, stemming etc).

Queries for the given use-cases:

```
1) title:india OR body:india OR country:india
2) title:yahoo OR body:yahoo OR emailAddress:yahoo
3) title:(Skeet OR Async) OR body:(Skeet OR Async)
4) title:asynchronous
5) lastName:skeet
```

Comment: I agree with you on the analyzers part. From the above response, I am not clear whether you are recommending single index for all business objects or separate index for each business object. For #1, #2 and #3 user should not be required to specify ORing between all attributes of an object. I will make #1, #2 and #3 clear by adding this constraint.

Comment: I'm recommending a single index (denormalized/flattened data) for the two business objects. For#1, #2 and #3, user will just enter some text and selects an option, based on the option, you will have to generate the query (with fields and boolean connectives) behind the scenes

Comment: Storing all the business objects, which are completely unrelated, in one index does not seem to me the way to go. I believe, lucene parallel search capabilities could not be utilized in that case.

Comment: In the question, I have mentioned only 2 business objects but there could be many. The end user mentioned in the question will be an advanced user. The search expression entered by user will be a Lucene Search expression and will be passed on to Lucene API as it is. In a multiple index strategy, is not there a way for the user to specify the index or the object type? For e.g. user specifying type:Blog for searching only blog entries.

Comment: @AnandPatel Index all the related business objects as part of single index.. why do you need multiple indexes? for parallelism? what is the size of your index?

Comment: Even if I put performance consideration aside I see other problems (may be due to my ignorance about Lucene). As per your solution a single Lucene document contains fields for both User and Blog. Lucene searcher gives back the matching documents for a given search expression. How do I know whether the document(s) returned by a searcher is/are a match for User and/or Blog?